# Generating a gradle android project on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to confgure an android gradle project ,on eclipse.
well , the problem is that i can't generate it directly on eclipse , in fact , i create an android project , then , when converting it to a gradle project , eclipse doesn't generate `build.gradle` file and other gradle files.
any help please ?
thank you.

Comment: What does the export to Gradle wizard says when you run it? Alternatively you could try importing it in Android Studio. The import there is more capable than the export from Eclipse (which we need to improve)

Comment: the problem is not about importing a project on eclipse , the problem is about CREATING a gradle android project on eclipse. the file " build.gradle " is not generated :/ PS : everything works great on android studio.